# How to use svg namespace in xhtml documents

Tags: html, xml, svg, xhtml, xml-namespaces

Can someone tell me why this document does not draw a circle on Chrome?

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<head></head>
<body>
  <svg:svg width="100" height="100">
     <svg:circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" />
  </svg:svg>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Works for me if named *.xhtml. If it fails to work when on a webserver, check that the document is served with an xml mimetype.

Comment: Same here. Works in an XHTML file, but not in an HTML file. Ditto with Mozilla.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

HTML prior to HTML5 does not support `<svg>` element. Like all HTML, HTML5 is not namespace aware and therefore it does not understand namespace prefixes. For a HTML parser, element
`<svg:svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">`
has different element name than
`<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">`
and that is why HTML(5) only supports literal `svg` element name for inline svg code.

Your solution is to either serve the page as XHTML, so it will be processed as XML and thus namespace aware, or you need to add a default namespace declaration on `<svg>` element for the svg namespace (like my latter example above) and then you can remove the svg namespace prefix while still continuing to use the svg namespace.

Answer (score 0):

tweaked the code, removed the svg from circle and 
http://jsfiddle.net/CLEZc/1/

```
<svg width="100" height="100">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks but I want to continue to use svg namespace. I know it works, but I can't find my error...