# Difference between svg:rect and rect

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I'm using D3-js for drawing `svg` elements. I can see that there are two ways of appending rectangles: use `svg:rect` and `rect`. What is the difference between them two?

In other words, are these two blocks of code equal?

```
svg.append("svg:rect")
.attr("width", "100%")
.attr("height", "100%")
.attr("stroke", "#000")
.attr("fill", "none")
```

---

```
svg.append("rect")
.attr("width", "100%")
.attr("height", "100%")
.attr("stroke", "#000")
.attr("fill", "none")
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use svg namespace in xhtml documents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22806022/how-to-use-svg-namespace-in-xhtml-documents)

Comment: @cgTag Just to make sure, if HTML5 is the case, `svg:rect` and `rect` have the same meaning?

Comment: Yes they are the same as long as you define which namespace is being used. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Namespaces_Crash_Course